# Role membership creation with ADFS login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, roles, adfs2.0

I am creating an MVC4 application that uses ADFS SSO login. I am trying to configure Roles so that I can restrict the Admin portion of the content But I am having some problems. I am hoping someone will be able to tell me how I can go about creating Roles when using ADFS? I have the pages restricted successfully I just need now to be able to Add the actual role itself and I am hoping someone can help me out.

In my **Global.asax** file I have enabled Roles using the code:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.Enabled = true;
```

And on my **HomeControllor** I tried using the following code:

```
if (hvm.User.isAdmin == true)
{
  if(!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
  Roles.AddUserToRole("jpmcfeely", "Admin");
}
```

This results in the following **error**:

```
This method can only be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase. Use PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute to declare a method that will be invoked in that phase.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to configure ADFS to map AD groups to roles.

[ADFS : Sending groups as claims](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/adfs-sending-groups-as-claims.html).

e.g. map "Token-Groups - Unqualified Names" to Roles. Then IsInRole works OOTB.

Comment: Hi there, will I need to make any special changes to the web.config file to set the Role Provider to be that of the role claim?

Comment: Not sure I understand but no, no changes are required. If you have an AD group called Admin and Joe is a memberOf that group, then with the mapping Joe will have a role of Admin.

Comment: And this will not require a SimpleMembership initializer? It will work right out of the box or will I have to check the claims against the role schema

Comment: OOTB - WIF will present you with a claim viz. http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role Admin